# How to save file in cordova project?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, html5-filesystem, cordova-plugin-file

I am trying to save a file with cordova-plugin-file.
The script seems to work but I cannot locate the file on the device and cdv: references don't seem to resolve.

```js
export const SaveFile = function(fFile, sFileName) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log("requestFilesystem", fFile);
        window.requestFileSystem(
            LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT,
            fFile.size,
            function(fs) {
                console.log("got fs", fs);
                fs.root.getFile(
                    sFileName,
                    { create: true, exclusive: false },
                    function(fileEntry) {
                        console.log("got fileentry", fileEntry);
                        fileEntry.createWriter(function(fileWriter) {
                            fileWriter.onwriteend = (eEvent) => {
                                console.log(
                                    `${ fileWriter.localURL } saved`,
                                    `${ fFile.size }kb`
                                );
                                resolve(fileWriter);
                            };

                            fileWriter.onerror = (eError) => {
                                console.error('onErrorCreateWriter', JSON.stringify(eError));
                                reject(eError);
                            };

                            fileWriter.write(fFile);
                        });
                    },
                    (eError) => {
                        console.error('onErrorCreateFile', eError);
                        reject(eError);
                    }
                );
            },
            (eError) => {
                console.error('onErrorLoadFs', eError.message);
                reject(eErroreError.message);
            }
        );
    });
};
```

I get the following in logs:

```
SaveFile.js:3 requestFilesystem Blob {size: 1707639, type: "video/webm"}
SaveFile.js:8 got fs FileSystem {name: "persistent", root: DirectoryEntry}
SaveFile.js:13 got fileentry FileEntry {isFile: true, isDirectory: false, name: "1eb4d914-3d81-a313-7744-bea86b90f042.mp4", fullPath: "/1eb4d914-3d81-a313-7744-bea86b90f042.mp4", filesystem: FileSystem, …}
SaveFile.js:16 cdvfile://localhost/persistent/1eb4d914-3d81-a313-7744-bea86b90f042.mp4 saved 1707639kb
```

So it saved right? but i dont see the video on fs and the cdvfile: ref in a video tag comes up broken.

Video tag trying to consume the file in a component is just:

```html
<video controls="" src="cdvfile://localhost/persistent/1eb4d914-3d81-a313-7744-bea86b90f042.mp4"></video>
```

Comment: Do you compile your code? i don't think export const SaveFile  works in ES5....

Comment: (commented repost) I compile with babel/webpack

Comment: @Eric any idea what might have happened to the file?

Comment: Show your code how you load the file once saved

Comment: I added it to the post, just a video tag, the url string comes out of the promise to redux and then passed into another component as prop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I found other steps that seem to work.
I needed to request a folder (and it had to be the cache folder) before I could find fies on the phone.

```js
export const SaveFile = function(fFile, sFileName) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(
            cordova.file.externalCacheDirectory,
            function(directoryEntry) {
                directoryEntry.getFile(
                    sFileName,
                    { create: true },
                    function(fileEntry) {
                        fileEntry.createWriter(
                            function(fileWriter) {
                                fileWriter.onwriteend = (eEvent) => {
                                    resolve(fileWriter.localURL);
                                };

                                fileWriter.onerror = (eError) => {
                                    console.error('onErrorCreateWriter', JSON.stringify(eError));
                                    reject(eError);
                                };

                                fileWriter.write(fFile);
                            },
                            (eError) => {
                                console.error('onErrorCreateFile', eError);
                                reject(eError);
                            }
                        );
                    }
                );
            }
        );
    });
};
```